# Aphorisms and idioms in The Witcher

Tags: dialogue, translation, the-witcher

There are a few sightly strange phrases featured in The Witcher TV series:

> *I'm not one to look a gift cock in the beak...* (Don't look a gift horse in the mouth)

> *Playing priest's ear...* (Playing devil's advocate)

Are these literal translations of e.g. Polish metaphors, or are they just invented for the show to give it an otherworldly feel?

Comment: See also: Cutting your ear to spite your face (Four marks) - would seem to imply these are Witcher-universe sayings (ie. this one based on elvish ears).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Polish version of 'don't look a gift horse in the mouth' is 'don't check the teeth of a horse you received as a gift' ("*darowanemu koniowi w zęby się nie zagląda*") ([source](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/darowanemu_koniowi_w_z%C4%99by_si%C4%99_nie_zagl%C4%85da)).
Similarly, devil's advocate seems to be [the same thing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/devil%27s_advocate) in Polish.

And, as far as I know, these idioms don't appear in the English translations. **Unless someone read the books in Polish and recognizes these expressions, I suppose they are indeed variations to give an "otherworldly feel" to the TV series.**
Moreover, I can imagine that 'playing the devil's advocate' could evoke unwanted associations, and potentially throw off viewers.

I'd like to add that I don't think one would tell the age of a cock by its beak. It might have been implemented as an additional layer of humour, since the one talking about it is Yarpen Zigrin, a dwarf, too short (at first glance) to be able to look a gift horse in the mouth.

Similarly, as 'devils' in the world of The Witcher are common entities, synonymous with sylvans (like Torque in Episode 2), 'playing priest's ear' makes a lot more sense in-universe.

Comment: I have read the books in polish and do not recognize these sayings. To fully complete your answer someone who played the games should also provide information

Comment: As far as I know, these phrases don't appear in the game, but sometimes characters refer to people's mouth's as beak. That is the only similarity I can think of.

Comment: Played all the games, the phrase "look a gift cock in the beak" definitely doesn't appear.  Not as certain about "priest's ear"; that phrase feels vaguely familiar though I can't say it's in the game either.